# Objecto con id como clave principal

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo los valores para el objeto final que quiero, pero no puedo hacer la llave primaria con una variable.

La variable `id` es como, por ejemplo, la siguiente:

```
'-MbPMzOh52y_LR0uAfG-';
```

La variable de los `datos` es como la siguiente:

```
{
    "title": "Titulo",
    "description": "Descripcion",
    "icon": "fas fa-user",
    "userEmail": "pacg@mail.com",
}
```

El **objeto final** que espero obtener es el siguiente:

```
{
    '-MbPMzOh52y_LR0uAfG-': {
        "title": "Titulo",
        "description": "Descripcion",
        "icon": "fas fa-user",
        "userEmail": "pacg@mail.com",
    }
}
```

El problema es que intento hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    id: { ...datos }
}
```

De esto obtengo el siguiente objeto:

```
{
    id: {
        "title": "Titulo",
        "description": "Descripcion",
        "icon": "fas fa-user",
        "userEmail": "pacg@mail.com",
    }
}
```

Donde la variable `id` no la logro colocar como llave del objeto de los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Podrías crear el objeto final primero y agregarle una propiedad donde la `key` es la
variable `id` y el `value` el objeto `datos`:

```
const id = '-MbPMzOh52y_LR0uAfG-';
const datos = {
    "title": "Titulo",
    "description": "Descripcion",
    "icon": "fas fa-user",
    "userEmail": "pacg@mail.com",
}
finalObj = {};
finalObj[id] = datos;
console.log(finalObj);
```

Resultado:

```
{
  '-MbPMzOh52y_LR0uAfG-': {
    title: 'Titulo',
    description: 'Descripcion',
    icon: 'fas fa-user',
    userEmail: 'pacg@mail.com'
  }
}
```

**2)** O bien podrías colocar la variable que contiene la `key` con corchetes:

```
const id = '-MbPMzOh52y_LR0uAfG-';
const datos = {
    "title": "Titulo",
    "description": "Descripcion",
    "icon": "fas fa-user",
    "userEmail": "pacg@mail.com",
}
finalObj = {[id]:datos};
console.log(finalObj);
```

Resultado (el mismo):

```
{
  '-MbPMzOh52y_LR0uAfG-': {
    title: 'Titulo',
    description: 'Descripcion',
    icon: 'fas fa-user',
    userEmail: 'pacg@mail.com'
  }
}
```